# Alt-tab switching workspaces if Chrome is in focus

Tags: shortcut-keys, google-chrome, workspaces

MATE 18.10

I have workspaces set up so that alt-tab cycles through windows in the current workspace. However if I am in a chrome window, alt-tab sends me to another chrome window on a different workspace.

Alt-tab does not appear as a shortcut in any chrome documentation I've seen.

So it looks like Chrome is grabbing the alt-tab or that some layer of MATE is passing it on rather than acting on it.

Does anyone have an idea about what's going on? And / or how to fix it?

Comment: I don't think it's Chrome doing it. Try reproducing the problem with another application.

Comment: @wjandrea Hm... I'm at a different machine right now (same configuration) and cannot replicate the issue. I'll take a look when I get back to the other machine. I should probably put this question on hold but don't know how to do it.

Comment: No need to put it on hold or anything, just edit it once you have the info and it will get bumped to the homepage

Comment: I think it's the window manager you use (probably Marco if you use MATE). You're probably hitting a case where some window on the another desktop is setting up the "attention" or "urgent" flag and Marco switches to that desktop on Alt+Tab instead of switching to your previous window. However, Marco is stupid enough NOT TO FOCUS the window asking for the attention. I'm just now dealing with a case where the target desktop is having around 60 windows open but I don't which window is asking for attention.

Comment: You probably should read this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85813/20336

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the problem is really some Chrome window setting a window manager flag `_NET_WM_STATE_DEMANDS_ATTENTION` and your window manager failing to focus correct window, you could run a script such as following to figure out the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright 2020 Mikko Rantalainen <mikko.rantalainen@iki.fi>
# License: MIT
set -e

# check 'wmctrl' has been installed
wmctrl --version > /dev/null || { echo "This script requires command 'wmctrl', aborting." 1>&2; exit 1; }

# save active window id
ACTIVE_ID=$(xprop -root | grep _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW\(WINDOW\) | sed 's/.*window id # //')

wmctrl -l | while read id desktop machine title
do
    if xprop -id "$id" | grep -q "_NET_WM_STATE_DEMANDS_ATTENTION"
    then
        printf "\nWindow id %s (%s) on desktop #%s demands attention:\n" "$id" "$machine" "$desktop"
        #xprop -id "$id" | grep -E '(WM_CLASS|^WM_NAME.*UTF8)'
        printf -- "- %s\n" "$title"
        if test "$1" = "--clear"
        then
        wmctrl -i -a "$id"
        sleep 1
        fi
    fi
done

if test "$1" = "--clear"
then
    wmctrl -i -a "$ACTIVE_ID"
else
    echo ""
    echo "Pass flag '--clear' to focus each window demanding attention" 1>&2
    echo "for 1 seconds to clear the demands attention flag" 1>&2
fi
```

Save the file e.g. as ~/bin/list-window-demands-attention and you can run it in terminal:

```
$ list-window-demands-attention

Window id 0x0320005e (desktop) on desktop #2 demands attention:
- linux - How to check actual RAM usage of tmpfs? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange - Google Chrome

Window id 0x03200079 (desktop) on desktop #2 demands attention:
- breaking-thunderbolt-security-bjorn-ruytenberg-20200417.pdf - Google Chrome

Pass flag '--clear' to focus each window demanding attention
for 1 seconds to clear the demands attention flag
```

That should be enough to figure out which windows you need to focus to clear the flag. If you don't mind about the actual windows and just want to clear the flag, you can pass `--clear` and the script will display each window for 1 seconds and then return to your window that was active before switching any window. The focused windows will be raised to top of window stack.

```
list-window-demands-attention --clear
```

If you don't want to wait for 1 second per window, feel free to comment out or remove the `sleep 1` above.

Answer (score -2):

According to the official [Google Help Center](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en) there is no Alt+Tab

Do a search in the Chrome web store for Shortkeys there ARE answers there. Which will allow you to override any default chrome shortcut keys. I found a couple. I can not make any suggestions though.

I would avoid asking questions like this in the future as this is a Chrome issue not Ubuntu.

According to this: https://www.computerhope.com/shortcut/chrome.htm
They can be set to alt+tab.

Edited: Moved stuff around to better show my answer.

Comment: Questions related to applications used on Ubuntu are not off-topic. We have questions about Chrome, Firefox, LibreOffice, etc here.

Comment: In addition, an answer here should be an *answer*. If merely a comment, it should be posted as a comment.

Comment: @vanadium I am not allowed to post as a comment.

Comment: Fine install this extension [Shortkeys (Custom Keyboard Shortcuts)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck?hl=en-US) and you should be able to override the Chrome shortcut keys. If they are really there.

Comment: @ChrisSmith Thanks Chris. I appreciate your help and understand your confusion. My Title was confusing so I've changed it. The issue is not Chrome shortcuts, it is that the desktop manager is not behaving to spec. The alt-tab is a desktop shortcut so the desktop should be handling that event and pulling it off the dispatch queue. It should not be reaching Chrome. So how is Chrome getting that keystroke? Is the DM failing to recognize that the Chrome instances are running on different workspaces?  Maybe. Or...

Comment: @StephenBoston - thanks for the understanding. Yeah I am trying to replicate your issue and can not do it. So I am kinda shooting in the dark. Which actually brings up another issue. If I can't replicate it, I wonder if some other underlying config is fowling things up. I have actually seen that a number of times where a third party issue brings up issues in the first 2. *shrug*

Comment: @ChrisSmith Yup. See my response to wjandrea's comment to the question. Looks like it is some local config issue.